# Use the result of a SQL query as an input for a WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, jdbc

I wonder if (and how?) I can use the result set of a query as an input for a WHERE clause in another query.

For instance, I have a query that fetches a list of "code" and I would like to `SELECT` all tuples from another table that have - as "code" value - either one of the previously fetched set's elements.

I'm using JDBC so I wonder if I need to use some Java programming or If I can directly use SQL.

Answer (score 2):

```
Select * from table2 -- this is another table from your question
  where code in (select code from table1); -- this is where clause that gets code from first table.
```

In fact query is equivalent to:

```
Select t2.* from table2 t2
  inner join table1 t1 on (t1.code = t2.code);
```

What in my opinion is better syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course you can

Try this for example

```
SELECT f1 , f2 , f3 , etc 
  FROM table1 
  WHERE f1 IN (SELECT field1 FROM table2)
```

Comment: Try  f1 IN (SELECT field1 FROM table2)

Comment: I know that (otherwise I wouldn't have posted my comment), you might want to consider **editing** your answer instead of commenting.

Answer (score 0):

The `in` keyword is fine for finding a single code value into another table, but to associate multiple columns, you should use an `inner join`:

```
SELECT employees.name
FROM employees
INNER JOIN departments
ON employees.department = departments.department 
AND employees.position = departments.position 
WHERE departments.jobtitle = 'Manager'
```

Another example using `in` clause as per @Kacper's comment, not that not all databases support this syntax:

```
SELECT employees.name
FROM employees
WHERE (department,position) IN 
(
SELECT department,position
FROM departments
WHERE jobtitle = 'Manager'
)
```

Comment: Oracle supporst such syntax `Where (c1,c2,c3) in select c1,c2,c3 form t2` so you can do multiple columns with `in`. However it is more readable with `join`